# how to convert an array into multidimensional

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array i want to convert into multidimensional.

**This is array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [packageid] => FGF1460676803
            [uniqueid] => uid1460676987
            [hotelname] => Jet Park Airport
            [Country] => New Zealand
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [packageid] => FGF1460678556
            [uniqueid] => uid1460678681
            [hotelname] => Mercure Windsor
            [Country] => New Zealand
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [packageid] => FGF1460678556
            [uniqueid] => uid1460678787
            [hotelname] => Jet Park Airport
            [Country] => New Zealand
        )
)
```

i have tried this code but it is not showing that i want.
this array fetched from mysql's two table first one is carry packageid and second is carrying uniqueid, hotelname, country so i joint it but i want to joint the below array but i am stuck how to do to using mysql or after fetching  array.

**This is mysql query**

```
SELECT
    c.packageid,
    `uniqueid`,
    `hotelname`,
    `Country`
FROM
    custinfo c,
    hotelcarttemp h
WHERE
    c.packageid = h.packageid
```

**PHP Code**

```
foreach ($json_decode_array1 as $row)
{
   $newArray[$row['packageid']][] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($newArray); echo '</pre>';
```

**Want OutPut**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (   
            [packageid] => FGF1460676803
            [hoteldata] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [uniqueid] => uid1460676987
                                [hotelname] => Jet Park Airport
                                [Country] => New Zealand
                            )
                    )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (   
            [packageid] => FGF1460678556
            [hoteldata] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [uniqueid] => uid1460678681
                                [hotelname] => Mercure Windsor
                                [Country] => New Zealand
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [uniqueid] => uid1460678787
                                [hotelname] => Jet Park Airport
                                [Country] => New Zealand
                            )
                    )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($json_decode_array1 as $row)
{
    $pid = $row['packageid'];
    if (!isset($newArray[$pid])) {
        $newArray[$pid] = array(
            'packageid' => $pid,
            'hoteldata' => array(),
        );
    }
    // if you don't want `packageid` 
    // to present in a arrays of `hoteldata`
    // you can `unset` this key:
    unset($row['packageid']);

    $newArray[$pid]['hoteldata'][] = $row;
}

// use array_values to turn array keys to numeric:
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
```

Comment: `$newArray[$pid]['hoteldata'] = $row;` this will override the array() instead of pushing the `$row`.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks a lot for your answer but it showing output like this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B74WYUnqb4GcSWVfWm9pN3JBRmM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @VijayKumar fixed my answer: removed `[]` in `$newArray[$pid] = array()`

Comment: @u_mulder  Do you really need to set 'hoteldata' => array(), on line 8. Is this necessary as you create that key in the end anyway?

Comment: @PetkoKostov it's not necessary but I like to know what I have here.

Comment: it working thanks a lot sir, but sir is there anyway to make key as normal index here $newArray[$pid], like this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B74WYUnqb4GcZ1FMTHQtSHZXMWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @u_mulder Thank so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$newArr = array();
    foreach($json_decode_array1 as $row) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['packageid'] = $row['packageid'];
        $temp['hoteldata'] = array(
            'uniqueid' => $row['uniqueid'],
            'hotelname' => $row['hotelname'],
            'Country' => $row['Country'],
        );
        $newArr[] = $temp;
    }
    echo '<pre>';print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_walk`, `array_shift` and `array_values` functions:

```
$result = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v) use(&$result) {   // $arr is your initial array
    $packageid = array_shift($v);
    if (!isset($result[$packageid])) {
        $result[$packageid] = ["packageid" => $packageid, "hoteldata" => [$v]];
    } else {
        $result[$packageid]["hoteldata"][] = $v;
    }    
});

print_r(array_values($result));
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [packageid] => FGF1460676803
            [hoteldata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [uniqueid] => uid1460676987
                            [hotelname] => Jet Park Airport
                            [Country] => New Zealand
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [packageid] => FGF1460678556
            [hoteldata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [uniqueid] => uid1460678681
                            [hotelname] => Mercure Windsor
                            [Country] => New Zealand
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [uniqueid] => uid1460678787
                            [hotelname] => Jet Park Airport
                            [Country] => New Zealand
                        )
                )
        )
)
```